# Error in './a.out': free(): invalid*** Error in `./allum1': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000023e13f0 ***

Tags: c

I'm working on a little game in C :
A board like this is displayed :

```
   |

  |||

 |||||

|||||||
```

And you have to take sticks and make the AI lose by letting it pick the LAST stick. Wanting to give the player the ability to chose the size of the board I have coded the following function :

```
char    **disp_board(int size)
{
    char  **tab;
    int   i;


    /* 
     * I malloc the board with the variable 'size' given by the user before the
     * game starts
    */

  if ((tab = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (size + 1))) == NULL)
    return (NULL);
  tab[size] = NULL;
  i = 0;
  while (i <= size)
  {
      if (i == 0)
      {
          if ((tab[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) + 1)) == NULL)
            return (NULL);
          tab[i] = my_strdup(my_strcat(tab[i], "|"));
          i++;                                           
      }
      if ((tab[i] = malloc(my_strlen(tab[i - 1]) + 3)) == NULL)
        return (NULL);
      tab[i] = my_strdup(my_strcat(tab[i - 1], "||"));
      i++;
  }
  disp_board2(tab, size);
  return (tab);
}
```

Please note that `my_strdup` and `my_strcat` are exactly like `strdup` and `strcat`.

But here is the problem ! The game works very often, but sometime (especially when I chose size 10 and 14) I receive the following message :

> "*** Error in ./allum1: free(): invalid next size (fast):
>   0x00000000022953f0 ***allum1: malloc.c:2365: sysmalloc: Assertion
>   `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) -
>   __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof
>   (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) &
>   ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) &&
>   ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed. Aborted"

So I figured the problem came from my mallocs and frees, I checked again and they all seemed logical !

Thank you in advance for your help, I really hope i'll get to solve this problem.

If you have any questions about the code please tell me.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `while (i < size)`?

Comment: I tried, I have the same result though but I believe you are right.

Comment: if you're `my_strdup()`ing, why need `malloc()`?

Comment: "Please note that my_strdup and my_strcat are exactly like strdup and strcat." -- Then why don't you just use `strdup` and `strcat`?

Comment: Actually no, it is i <= size otherwise the board is not totally filled.

Comment: `my_strcat(tab[i], "|")` is going to have an awfully hard time finding a terminator in the buffer pointed to by `tab[i]` from which to base the `cat` since none was established after that raw-malloc. The ensuing memory leak is a bonus into itself.

Comment: @DevSolar For scholar reasons, we recoded them to understand the logic behind it, but both would work.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm not sure I get it, how would I solve this problem? Thanks for your answer anyways :)

Comment: @Aruixe: The problem with statements like "both would work" in the context of a question like this should be obvious. Before posting, you should have *isolated* the problem, which would include a) replacing your own "scholary" implementations with the standard ones, and checking if the error persists, and b) making your example self-contained, i.e. enabling others to trial & error instead of visiting their crystal balls trying to figure out what *might* be the problem.

Comment: `strcat` works by finding the *exiting* termination point of the target string, then concatenating the second input string from there. `malloc` just allocates memory. there is no terminator established in the resulting buffer, so you're code invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: ` free(): invalid next size` is because you are trying to free() a pointer that wasn't allocated my malloc or you may be trying to free() more than once. `I don't see any code with free() in the above program. So post  verifiable code.`

Comment: @DevSolar Oh ok, I'm rather new to this website and I'm learning the tips and tricks, thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Aruixe: That's actually debugging 101, unrelated to this (or any other) website. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [here](http://sscce.org/), and if I may be so bold to add my own take to these two, [here](http://rootdirectory.de/wiki/MacheteDebugging). Have fun!

Comment: Since there is no `free()` in your code it's not possible to know whether you did `free()` twice or not.

Comment: @iharob The problem is there are a few frees in the code and it's pretty big, but of course I understand you can't help without something to look at. But I free the tab in the main before closing the program.

Comment: If you are on linux, use `gdb` and check where exactly is the faulty `free()`. Also, no matter how large your code is, you should be able to isolate the problem, if you do it then you also would have solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
      if ((tab[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) + 1)) == NULL)
        return (NULL);
      tab[i] = my_strdup(my_strcat(tab[i], "|"));
```

When you get back a pointer from `malloc`, it doesn't point to anything specific, certainly not a valid string that you can concatenate something onto. Passing `tab[i]` to `my_strcat` (assuming it's a concatenation function) makes no sense until `tab[i]` has some sane contents.

Answer (score 0):

You make unnecessary complication in your program, making a dependency in the n-th row building on (n-1)-st row while you can create a row directly.  Stop `strdup`ing, use simple `malloc`+`memset` to create and fill the row:

```
for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if ((tab[i] = malloc(2*i + 2)) == NULL) // create a string
      return (NULL);
    memset(tab[i], '|', 2*i + 1);           // fill it
    tab[i][2*i + 1] = 0;                    // add a terminator
}
```